# Execute Dask Graph in distributed workers

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I have this Dask Graph that works in a non-distributed environment as described [here](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/graphs.html).

Now, what I need is to execute each function in the graph in a distributed worker. How can this be achieved? Should I submit the `get` ?

```
data1 = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000 ]
data2 = [ 100, 200, 300, 400, 500 ]

def sum_all(x):
    return sum(x[0]) + sum(x[1])

def sum_10(x):
    return x + 10

graph2 = { 'data' : (data1, data2) }
graph2['out2'] = (sum_10, 'out1')
graph2['out1'] = (sum_all, 'data')

result = get(graph2, ['out1', 'out2'])
print(str(result))
(16500, 16510)
```

Comment: Every scheduler implementation has a `get` function https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/scheduler-overview.html#the-get-function ; but *why* are you doing this?

Comment: I need to run user defined functions in parallel on workers. The user also defines the dependencies between functions.

Comment: Please see https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/delayed.html before attempting to make your own arbitrary graphs.